# Play speechRecognition audio - Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, angular-ui-router

I built an application using speechRecognition.

```
    startListening() {
      let options = {
        language: 'en-US'
      }
      this.speechRecognition.startListening().subscribe(matches => {
        this.matches = matches;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      });
      this.isRecording = true;
    }
```

I would like to know if there is a possibility to listen to the audio I recorded again?

Answer (score 0):

That's very much possible. You can use cordova-file-transfer plugin and save the audio to the device. You can then load it from the device to play the audio.

Read [this documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) which says more about cordovas file transfer plugin

Comment: Since I would get the speechRecognition audio, it returns only one string array. Does it generate a temporary audio?